# Angular Route Precheck

Tags: angularjs

I have angular app

```
   <body ng-app="appName">
        <div class="container" ng-view=""></div>
```

I have routes

```
 $routeProvider
  .when('/', {
    templateUrl: 'partials/main',
    controller: 'MainCtrl'
  })
  .when('/login', {
    templateUrl: 'partials/login',
    controller: 'LoginCtrl'
  })
```

I want to call a service before every route. Say for example if I have not loaded the profile data I want load profile data and store it in $rootscope. How should I do this?

Comment: Dont store it in `rootScope` - make a service and persist the data there.

Comment: @tymeJV is correct, don't use `$rootScope` as a storage area you're better off creating a service to store global application data.

Comment: If that's the case I would need to call service in all routes, rite?

Comment: @neolivz4ever you would need to inject the service into the route's controller if you intend to use the data in that route.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `$route's` resolve property to call a function that will be executed prior to the route change:

From the AngularJS API Docs:

`resolve - {Object.<string, function>=} - An optional map of dependencies which should be injected into the controller. If any of these dependencies are promises, the router will wait for them all to be resolved or one to be rejected before the controller is instantiated. If all the promises are resolved successfully, the values of the resolved promises are injected and $routeChangeSuccess event is fired. If any of the promises are rejected the $routeChangeError event is fired. The map object is:`

This is usually meant to inject the route's controller with additional parameters but there's no reason you could do more.

```
$routeProvider
    .when('/login',{
        templateUrl : 'partials/login',
        controller: 'loginCtrl',
        resolve : {
            some_extra_controller_param : ['$route','someService',function($route,someService){
                // do stuff here that you would feel necessary to have done prior to route change
                someService.doSomething();
                return true; // or return an object of data maybe your controller could use
            ]}
        }
    });
```

Of course the `some_extra_controller_param` will be injected into your controller as the last parameter so make sure you return something in the resolve, `loginCtrl` might look like this:

```
.controller('loginCtrl',['$scope','some_extra_controller_param',function($scope,some_extra_controller_param){
    ...
]});
```

EDIT:  You may want to setup the resolve function to use `promises` as the route's controller will wait on promises to be "resolved" before instantiating the controller.

**EDIT:**

```
var myBeforeRouteCheck = {
    something_to_be_resolved : ['$route','someService',function($route,someService){
        // assuming your service runs some kind of function that returns a promise
        return someService.someFunc().then(
            function(data){ 
                ...do successful things...;
                return somethingToInjectedParam;
            },
            function(){ 
                ... error ...
                return false;
            });
    }]
};
```

then in your route:

```
.when('/login',{
    ...
    resolve: myBeforeRouteCheck
}
```

Comment: How do i share this across all routes without copy pasting?

Comment: You can setup an object variable that you can assign to the resolve property

Comment: Ohh.. Pure js solution :) I was thinking something would be available in angular.

Comment: Well you could attach the object to a module or controller instance: `var myCtrl = angular.module('someApp').controller('someCtrl',function(){ ...});` and then do `myCtrl.toBeResolved = { ... resolve object props ...}` and then in the route `.when('/route',{ resolve: myCtrl.toBeResolved })`